# Python Regex first match

Tags: python, regex

I would like to delete the first occuring pattern in a string. There are plenty of answers at stackoverflow which suggest to use the ?-symbol to make the regex non-greedy, however I couldn't make it work.

```
text = "Some text, more text, even more text"
print(re.sub(".+?, ", "", text))
```

The print-statement delivers

```
even more text
```

and I am expecting

```
more text, even more text
```

Comment: There is an answer for this, too. `re.sub` has a count argument, pass it as `1`

Comment: Don't use the global flag